# Correct file tree structure for django translations

Tags: django, tree, translation

Looking at

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/

I'm missing the correct file structure for the "locale" folder:

`myproject/locale/myapp/locale/en`

is this correct? why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, correct path is `myproject/myapp/locale/en`.

Or you can create project-wide `myproject/locale/en` and add this setting:

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)
```